# Отфильтровать массив объектов, если значение хотя бы одного ключа равно false

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, фильтрация

Есть массив вида

```
[
   {
      "isSquare":true,
      "hasBorder":true,
      "isRed":true,
      "isBig":true
   },
   {
      "isSquare":true,
      "hasBorder":false,
      "isRed":true,
      "isBig":true
   },
   {
      "isSquare":false,
      "hasBorder":true,
      "isRed":true,
      "isBig":true
   },
   {
      "isSquare":true,
      "hasBorder":true,
      "isRed":false,
      "isBig":true
   },
   {
      "isSquare":true,
      "hasBorder":true,
      "isRed":true,
      "isBig":false
   }
]
```

Я хочу его отфильтровать так, что если хотя бы один из ключей равен false, то объект не будет выводиться. То есть фактически получить только нулевой объект, если смотреть по данному примеру. Есть ли вариант фильтровать, не приводя названия ключей, просто перебирая все?

Comment: Пока пришел к такому решению let result = jsonValue.filter( e => !Object.values(e).includes(false)). Но, может быть, есть решения получше?

Comment: А чем не устраивает такое решение?

Comment: Ну меня оно устраивает, просто я нуб от слова совсем и все решения, которые я придумываю, мне кажутся неправильными. :) Спасибо. Тогда отвечу на вопрос сам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пришел к такому решению:

```
 jsonValue.filter(e => !Object.values(e).includes(false))
```

Спасибо за внимание :)

Answer (score 1):

Мой способ реализации, уверен можно лучше, просто решил себя попробовать.

```js
let test =
[
   {
      "isSquare":true,
      "hasBorder":true,
      "isRed":true,
      "isBig":true
   },
   {
      "isSquare":true,
      "hasBorder":false,
      "isRed":true,
      "isBig":true
   },
   {
      "isSquare":false,
      "hasBorder":true,
      "isRed":true,
      "isBig":true
   },
   {
      "isSquare":true,
      "hasBorder":true,
      "isRed":false,
      "isBig":true
   },
   {
      "isSquare":true,
      "hasBorder":true,
      "isRed":true,
      "isBig":false
   }
];

let newObj = test.filter((obj) =>
{
  return !Object.values(obj).some((value) => !value)
});
console.log(newObj)
```